# Accessing two TextMeshPro objects separately in same scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two TextMeshPro objects in the same scene. Whenever I try to access the second object, it's the first one that gets used, even though I use separate scripts for them. How do I distinguish between the two?

I deleted the script, but it used the following statements:

```
public TextMeshProUGUI name; 

name.text = Globals.player;
```

Comment: Would you mind adding your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code wouuld be appreciated but following your description of the problem, are you using a `GetComponent` method to retrieve the `TextMeshPro`'s components ? If it's the case, `GetComponent` only retrieve the first component matching the type you request it to find.

I would recommend you to either use `GetComponents` with an "s" that will give you an array of every component that matched the type on your gameObject

OR

Use serialized member variable (`public` or `[SerializeField] private`) to reference the component on the script you want

If the problem is different, pleaze leave a comment ;)

Comment: Serialize field resolved my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My pleasure, don't forget to mark this question as resolved then